# Run Powershell with argument using Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I am trying run the power shell script on the remote computer, but its not working. tried below two option its fails.

```
Invoke-Command  -Session $Session -FilePath "c:\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 -CertValidityDays 3650 -EnableCredSSP  -Verbose"
```

Method 2:

```
$script = [scriptblock]::Create("c:\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 -CertValidityDays 3650 -EnableCredSSP  -Verbose")

$result =Invoke-Command  -Session $Session  -script $script
```

How can I run this script on remote computer?

Thanks
SR

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: if you use enter-pssession and run it at your prompt through remoting does it work?

Comment: @thomschumacher Thanks for the tips, the command works with enter-pssession.

Comment: @DeanOC looks like special character added for hypen. now I removed it. `The term '' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct`

Answer (score 0):

```
function Send-RemoteCommand
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true,ValueFromPipeline=$True,HelpMessage="Computer Name to run command on.")]
    [String]$ComputerName,
    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $true,ValueFromPipeline=$false,HelpMessage="Command to be ran on remote computer.")]
    [String]$Command
    )

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {param($Arg) Invoke-Expression -Command $Arg} -ArgumentList "$Command"
}

Send-RemoteCommand -ComputerName "ComputerNameHere" -Command "YourPowerShellCommandsHere"
```

This is the function I normally use to send remote commands to users computers on our domain. Wrote it so I don't have to remember how to do the Invoke-Command syntax correctly :) My only thought is that i'm not sure if this would work with a script, but it does work with one liners. Up to you if you want to give it a go! Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the code, this code didn't work for my script. there is hidden character in my script, after removing it scriptblock worked.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. Feel free to select an answer for your post.

Answer (score 0):

After removing special character from the script, below code worked.

```
$script = [scriptblock]::Create("c:\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 -CertValidityDays 3650 -EnableCredSSP  -Verbose")

$result =Invoke-Command  -Session $Session  -script $script
```